# How to set absolutely new index to pandas DataFrame, not based on previous index-data relation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I assign an absolutely new index to my data without any relation to the old index?

I know the `reindex` method

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [2,3,4,5]})
df

    a   b
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   5

df.reindex([1,2,3,4])

    a   b
1   2.0 3.0
2   3.0 4.0
3   4.0 5.0
4   NaN NaN
```

... but I just want to modify the row index in order to get

```
    a   b
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   4
4   4   5
```

Remarks:

1. I know that I can construct a dataframe with a preassigned index using the `DataFrame` constructor. I need exactly modify an existent DataFrame.
2. In this particular case `DataFrame.shift` can work - but what if I need to assign an arbitrary custom index, not shift the existing one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In chained method calls it might be useful to know the trick that you can call `set_index` with non-existing labels as long as you wrap the labels you want to set in another list.

```
>>> df.set_index([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
   a  b
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
4  4  5
>>>
>>> df.set_index([['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']])
   a  b
w  1  2
x  2  3
y  3  4
z  4  5
```

I don't really know *why* this works. Looking at the documentation of [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) my best guess is that this is a special case of creating a multi-index with just one level, like the last example from the documentation

```
df.set_index([[1, 2, 3, 4], 'year'])
```

but omitting the second element `'year'`.

Comment: It's a way of differentiating setting a list of columns as the index (columns w, x, y, z) and setting a list of row labels. The second one requires a list of lists.

Comment: "column label or list of column labels / arrays" kind of implies that. :) It's not the best wording of course.

Comment: @ayhan Especially since it's directly under "Set the DataFrame index (row labels) using one or more **existing** columns."

Comment: I noticed that too. I'll send a request to edit it when I have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass whatever you want to `df.index`, if it's a collection that is the same length as your dataframe:

```
df.index = range(1,5)
>>> df
   a  b
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
4  4  5

df.index = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'index']
>>> df
       a  b
this   1  2
is     2  3
an     3  4
index  4  5
```

Also, if it were just a question of adding one to your original index, you can use the in-place `+` operator:

```
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  4  5

>>> df.index += 1

>>> df
   a  b
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
4  4  5
```

Comment: Ok, it works. Thanks)
But what about some method, for ability to use it in difficult chain operations, without dummy variables? Such method does not exist, right? Example: s.iloc[1:] / s.iloc[:-1].reindex(s.iloc[1:].index) . This example does not work actually, but with this example I want to demonstrate, what I want

Comment: See @timgeb's comment, you can maybe use `.set_index()`. I'm not sure what you're aiming for with the `iloc` and `reindex` example

Answer (score 1):

To modify the index of an existing DataFrame, simply do

```
df.index = [1,2,3,4]
```

If you want to do this with a method, then timgeb's answer is probably best for this particular case.  Alternatively, you could define your own `DataFrame` method as follows.

```
def reindex2(self, newindex, inplace=False):
    if inplace:
        reindexed = self
    else:
        reindexed = self.copy()
    reindexed.index = newindex
    return reindexed
pd.DataFrame.reindex2 = reindex2
del reindex2
```

Now you can do

```
df.reindex2([1,2,3,4])
```

to get your desired result.